# destruction of @bean created executor

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-async

I have the following annotationconfig in Spring 4

```
    @Bean(name = "replicationThreadExecutor")
public Executor replicationThreadExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolCoreSize);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolCoreSize);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

What I am concerned with is the destruction of the `Executor`. Will Spring recognize that the dynamic type of `Executor` is an instance of `DisposableBean` and destroy it or do I need to change the return type into `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for that to work?

Comment: As a rule of thumb for Java based configuration be as specific as you can be as those are inspected whilst creating the application context. Hence in this case it might be that a callback isn't registered (although with a `DisposableBean` it just might work).

Answer (score 0):

If you call `registerShutdownHook` method on `ConfigurableApplicationContext` all  destroy methods on singleton beans are called

Comment: If the process dies the threadpool will go with it. The issue I (potentially) have is with redeploys of the application.

Comment: What's the problem with redeploy, and what behavior do you expect at redeploy

Comment: on redeploy I expect the spring context to be destroyed and want the Threadpool to be cleanly destroyed.

Comment: on redeploy spring container call destroy method for all singleton beans, even for web app, if you want a customer behavior you can  configure a spring bean  which implements ApplicationListener and wait for ContextClosedEvent there you can add some behavior on destroy Threadpool